# Iterating HashMap in Android and replacing values

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Hi I have a HashMap with {key,value} as `{var1:10},{var2:20}` etc.

I have another hashMap with {key,value} as `{value,import android   droid = android.Android()  average = (var1 + var2)/2 droid.makeToast('Hello World' +str(average))}`.

I want to replace the variable names with values from the first hashMap.

Can anyone help me how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your first map is of type `HashMap<String, Integer>` and your second map is of type `HashMap<String, String>` you could iterate over both maps and perform string replacement:

```
for (Entry<String, String> e1 : map2.entrySet()) {
    String s = e1.getValue();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> e2 : map1.entrySet()) {
        s = s.replace(e2.getKey(), e2.getValue().toString());
    }
    map2.put(e1.getKey(), s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Can u please say how do I use a regular expression for  replacing the entire word? @Arthur Dent

Comment: Instead of `replace` you can use `replaceAll` which takes a regular expression as first parameter.